# How to get "usage guidance" for a tag from the Stack Exchange API?

Tags: support, api, tags

Stack Exchange site tags have "usage guidance", both a 1-paragraph "excerpt" and a longer tag description, as e.g. for JavaScript [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/info).  Is it possible to get this data through the API?  The options listed under the "filter" menu on the [API docs](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/tags) don't seem to include it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the `/tags/{tags}/wikis` method for this. [Here](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/wikis-by-tags#tags=javascript&filter=!9Z(-wqVFv&site=stackoverflow&run=true) is a link to the documentation page, including the necessary parameters for the JavaScript tag. By default, the body of the tag wiki isn't returned, so you'll need a [custom filter](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/filters).

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "excerpt_last_edit_date": 1570698075,
      "body_last_edit_date": 1573208252,
      "excerpt": "JavaScript (not to be confused with Java) is a high-level, dynamic, multi-paradigm, object-oriented, prototype-based, weakly-typed, and interpreted language used for both client-side and server-side scripting. Its primary use is in the rendering and manipulation of web pages. Use this tag for questions regarding ECMAScript and its various dialects/implementations (excluding ActionScript and Google-Apps-Script).",
      "body": "\n\n<p><strong><a href=\"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript\" rel=\"nofollow noreferrer\">JavaScript</a></strong> (a dialect of ECMAScript) is a high-level, dynamic, multi-paradigm, object-oriented, <a href=\"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype-based_programming\" rel=\"nofollow noreferrer\">prototype-based</a>, weakly-typed, and interpreted language traditionally used for client-side scripting in web browsers.",
      "tag_name": "javascript"
    }
  ],
  "has_more": false,
  "quota_max": 10000,
  "quota_remaining": 9871
}
```

<sub>(note: I have omitted part of the `body` since otherwise this answer would be too long)</sub>